# how to run an Ezee game in Python with 1000 rolls

Tags: python

So far I have Made my whole program of Ezee but I need to simulate it 1000 times at once and I am stuck on how to do that. Here is my code:

```html
<script src="//repl.it/embed/HzBl/24.js"></script>
```

Comment: for i in range(1000): game()?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean running the game function 1000 times *simultaneously*. Then you'll need to do threading:

```
import threading
threads = []
for i in range(1000):
    th = threading.Thread(name=str(i),target = game)
    threads.append(th)
    th.start()
for each in threads:
    each.join()
```

However due to the design of your game function, specifically it outputting while running rather than returning the value to be output, threading glitches could occur.

*EDIT*

I've edited and implemented it in your code:

```
global results
results = []
def game(debug=False): 
    '''rolls 14 dice and repeats until getting an Ezee
    returns the number of rolls made.
    '''
    dice = first_roll()
    if debug:
        print dice
    counter = 0
    while not won(dice):
        counter += 1
        reroll_many(dice)
        if debug:
            print dice

    results.append(counter)


######

import threading
threads = []
for i in range(1000):
    th = threading.Thread(name=str(i),target = game)
    threads.append(th)
    th.start()
for each in threads:
    each.join()

for each in results:
    print(each)
```

Comment: It doesn't work for my program, I need something that actually works. At home I am spending hours trying to figure it out because I need to submit it as a project.

Comment: Thanks for the help though hazz303

Comment: Sorry I forgot the th.start() :P. Fixed now but will give weird printed values. Try having game return a value rather than print it?

Comment: If the answer worked for you could you select it as the answer to your question? Glad I could help